# How to create recursive function to hide show the child parent question

Tags: javascript, angular, logic, survey

Here the example JSON. I want hide show the question based on visible if property in the Json.

```
Q1 ==> Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q8,Q12
Q5 ==> Q6,Q7
Q6 => Q9,Q10
Q10=>Q11
```

Json example:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Q1",
        "visibleIf": null,
        "hasChild": true,
        "isparentQuestion": true,
        "label": "Question 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "name": "Q2",
        "visible": false,
        "isparentQuestion": false,
        "visibleIf": "Q1",
        "label": "Question 2"



    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "name": "Q3",
        "visible": false,
        "isparentQuestion": false,
        "visibleIf": "Q2",
        "label": "Question 3"

    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "name": "Q4",
        "visible": false,
        "isparentQuestion": false,
        "visibleIf": "Q3",
        "label": "Question 4"
    }
]
```

```
   recursiveFunc(isChecked, question, item) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (item.name == question.visibleIf) {
        question.visible = true
      }
    } else {

      if (item.name == question.visibleIf) {
        question.visible = false;
        //           
      } else if (question.visibleIf == null) {
        question.visible = true;
      }
      else {
        this.temp = question;
        if (question.hasChild) {
          this.recursiveFunc(false, question, this.temp)
        }

      }
```

Here the example
   [Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zgudm)

Comment: Please, include code in the post and ask questions. Not ask for implementing it for you.

Comment: Do your questions always have two levels of nesting?

Comment: Why use recursion? Can't you simply keep an array of checked questions and then map over all questions and show/hide based on if the value is present in the array of checked questions?

Comment: @Bloatlord , it's work for first level question . how it's work for child nested question

Comment: @AntonMedvedev Add the Same code It's easy to understand. Nothing else.

Comment: @maury844 My question will have n level of nesting

Comment: please add the first part like `Q1 ==> Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q8,Q12` in a literal notation (ready for use) and the result of the wanted part.